# Recurring Billing in authorize.net- With a discount for n months - Php?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am new to authorize.net. I need some information which is very importent for my project.

1) Can Authorize.net do recurring billing that changes month to month. ?
2) can there be discount for particular month ?
3) What types of cards are accepted for it.?
4) Is both debit and credit cards are accepted ? 
5) Are there any tutorials or libraries for this ? 
6) Is server integrated method easy or advance integrated method ?

I am not able to find info over internet please help 
Please find me a solution for this. or give me any reference link to search for the details. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at http://www.chargify.com which has a nice API to manage recurring billing systems. They handle all the transactions between your website them and Authorize.net.

You can give discounts on memberships any month you want. Use their API for that and lower the price on a plan for your customers then bring it back up the following month.

Authorize.net is a gateway. Your merchant provider should accept most cards Visa, Mastercard, Amex, Discovery.

Debit cards are accepted if they have the Visa or Mastercard symbol.